# Yii2 Dynamic model and Ajax missing data issue

Tags: ajax, dynamic, model, yii2

I get only partial data in controller. here is the situation

my action in controller that show the view with the form:

```
$model_sms = array();
            $model_sms = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['sms_code', 'iduser', 'mail_status', 'signup_control']);
            $model_sms->addRule(['sms_code, iduser, mail_status, signup_control'], 'required');
            $model_sms->addRule(['iduser, mail_status, signup_control'], 'integer');
            $model_sms->addRule('sms_code', 'string', ['min' => 5, 'max' => 5]);
            $model_sms->iduser = $user->id;
            $model_sms->mail_status = $mail_status;
            $model_sms->signup_control = 1;


            return $this->renderAjax('_sms_confirmation', ['model_sms' => $model_sms]);
```

then the view code is here

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
?>

<div class=" site-login">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'frmsmsconfirm', 'action'=>'/index.php?r=site/confirmsms']); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>    
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="formSeparator"><span>Enter SMS code</span></div>
            <p class="logtxt">Please fill out the following fields to login:</p>
            <?php
                                echo $form->field($model_sms, 'iduser')->hiddenInput()->label(false);
                                echo $form->field($model_sms, 'mail_status')->hiddenInput()->label(false);
                                echo $form->field($model_sms, 'signup_control')->hiddenInput()->label(false);

                echo $form->field($model_sms, 'sms_code', [
                    'feedbackIcon' => [
                        'default' => 'phone',
                        'success' => 'ok',
                        'error' => 'exclamation-sign',
                        'defaultOptions' => ['class'=>'cw']
                    ]
                ])->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Enter SMS code', 'class'=>'newxinput xinput'])->label('SMS code');
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="scforget">
                    If you did not receive SMS <?= Html::a('send it again', ['site/smsresend']) ?>.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-10"><br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'xsubbtn', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
            </div><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>      
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>

<script>
 $('#frmsmsconfirm').on('submit', function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             e.stopImmediatePropagation();
             var form = $(this);
             alert('ajax start');
             alert(form.serialize());

            $.ajax({
                     url    : form.attr('action'),
                     type   : 'post',
                     data   : form.serialize(),
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        alert('radi a ne radi... hm');
                       $('#sc_content').html(response);

                    },
                    error: function ()
                    {
                        console.log('internal server error');
                    }
                });
        });


            </script>
```

I get all correct data in alert(serialize.form), but when it is passed to another action in controller I only get sms_code, other 3 fields come blank... here is the code...

```
         $model_sms = array();

        $model_sms = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['sms_code', 'iduser', 
        'mail_status', 'signup_control']);
            $model_sms->addRule(['sms_code, iduser, mail_status, 
      signup_control'], 'required');
            $model_sms->addRule(['iduser, mail_status, signup_control'], 
       'integer');
            $model_sms->addRule('sms_code', 'string', ['min' => 5, 'max' => 
     5]);
    $model_sms->load(Yii::$app->request->post());


        echo $model_sms->sms_code.'- xxx - <br>';
        echo $model_sms->iduser.'- xxx - <br>';
        echo $model_sms->mail_status.'- xxx - <br>';
        echo $model_sms->signup_control.'- xxx - <br>';

       exit;
```

Does anybod have any idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at your 2 addRule() definitions:

```
$model_sms->addRule(['sms_code, iduser, mail_status, signup_control'], 'required');
$model_sms->addRule(['iduser, mail_status, signup_control'], 'integer');
```

should be:

```
$model_sms->addRule(['sms_code', 'iduser', 'mail_status', 'signup_control'], 'required');
$model_sms->addRule(['iduser', 'mail_status', 'signup_control'], 'integer');

The 1st parameter of addRule should be an array of attributes.
```